How to change the font of TOC in class memoir to sans-serif?
I have a tex file
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor,hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=blue,
  filecolor=blue,
  urlcolor=red,
  citecolor=magenta,
  bookmarksopen=true,
  bookmarksopenlevel=3
}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\definecolor{light_blue}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}
\renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\bfseries\sffamily\color{light_blue}}% Set \chapter style 
\setsecheadstyle{\normalfont\bfseries\sffamily\color{light_blue}}% Set \section style
\setsubsecheadstyle{\normalfont\bfseries\sffamily\color{light_blue}}% Set \subsection style

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Acknowledgment}
\chapter*{Abstract}

\begingroup
\hypersetup{linkcolor=light_blue}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\tableofcontents*
\endgroup

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Motivation}
\section{Background}
\subsection{Well-posedness of some SDEs}
\subsection{Well-posedness of some PDEs}

\end{document}


The sentence 1 Introduction is not formatted as sans-serif. Could you elaborate how to make it sans-serif?

That font is governed by \cftchapterfont and \cftchapterpagefont, which you can update as needed. For example, adding
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\sffamily\bfseries}% Chapter number/title in ToC
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\sffamily\bfseries}% Chapter page number in ToC

to your preamble results in this output:

